# Discord.py .connect() not working (PyNaCl)

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been following many different tutorials on how to code a Music Bots on discord. But there has been ONE command that they ALL had in common; ".connect()". For some reason every time I try to use this command I get an error that says:

- "PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice"

I have downloaded it using "Pip install PyNaCl" and "Pip install --user PyNaCl" but it [says](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksrIQ.png) that I already have it. I made sure I have it using the "list" command in the Terminal.

-
Another problem I'm having is Importing it. I am using Replit to code the bot and I have tried both [import "nacl"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eam3o.png) and "import pynacl", but they return the same thing

-
At the time of sending this I re-tested the code that gave me the:
"PyNaCl library needed in order to use voice" Error and now the error turned into:
This[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1R8ue.png) with this [CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ub8R5.png)

Comment: Make sure you install voice support `py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py[voice]`

Comment: Also, post code - not screenshots

Comment: How i post code? LOL

Comment: C:\Users\jteyr>py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py[voice]       |||||||||||||||||||||| it returned: ||||||||||||||||||||||
'py' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you run the command to install PyNaCl you use the same python executable as the one you use to start your bot.

For your last point, this happens if the member using the join command is not connected in a channel, therefore `ctx.author.channel` is `None`

Comment: Can you give me an example of python executable that starts a bot. i dont really understand that.
------------
For your last point// LOL I forgot :D let me try again real quick and see what it returns

Comment: yep it returns the old problem of PyNaCl

Comment: for example `"C:\python.exe" -m pip install PyNaCl` and then using `"C:\some_other_folder\python.exe" main.py`, in this case you will have installed PyNaCl on one installation of python, but execute the main in another installation so it doesn't have the module

That's why I recommend installing with `python -m pip install PyNaCl` if you use `python main.py` to run your bot

Comment: But when I run "python -m pip install PyNaCl" it says its already satisfied

Comment: and do you run your bot with `python main.py` ? If so, I don't really know what could be the problem
You can try uninstalling all the version of python of your computer and reinstall only 1 (and then reinstall your libraries), this usually works when libraries are not detected

Answer (score 0):

I use Replit too, and after some playing around I managed to solve it.
First, import pip.

```
import pip
```

Then,

```
pip.main(["install", "discord.py[voice]", "-U", "--upgrade"])
```

It should work after that, it did for me.